# Python access server urlopen()

Tags: python, url, web

I wanted to access data stored in a site using the following code:

```
import urllib
import re
import json

htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1&r=eSxQS2SI").read()

print htmltext

#data = json.load(htmltext)
```

I get a response:

```
You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;www&#46;cmegroup&#46;com&#47;CmeWS&#47;mvc&#47;ProductSlate&#47;V1&#47;List&#47;500&#47;1&#63;" on this server.<P>
```

Is there a way to get access to this information, or is there another way to extract info from the provided link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the link is accessible from a browser, it looks like the server does not allow plain HTML requests (without a User-Agent header). We can mimic such a request using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1&r=eSxQS2SI"
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

your_json = response.read()
response.close()
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

The webserver seems to block requests based on the user-agent.

Using a different http user-agent will do the trick.

In addition you should use the 'requests' module for Python giving you a more flexible
control over your request data.

```
wget -U Mozilla "http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1&r=eSxQS2SI"

--2013-05-19 17:24:54--  http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1&r=eSxQS2SI
Resolving www.cmegroup.com (www.cmegroup.com)... 23.45.237.124
Connecting to www.cmegroup.com (www.cmegroup.com)|23.45.237.124|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 17349 (17K) [application/json]
Saving to: ‘1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1&r=eSxQS2SI’
```

Comment: so the -U flag will set it as a user-agent?

Answer (score 2):

I was working on this also using liburl2 this is the answer I ended up with, after being able to load the page in chrome I realised it was the server blocking based on the header that was being sent, so I came up with this:

```
import urllib2
import re
import json

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open('http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=1&r=eSxQS2SI')
data = json.load(response)
print data
```

Which works like a treat.